# TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$('#popupDatepicker').datepicker...')

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

```
<input type = "text" size = 15 name = "popupDatepicker" id = "popupDatepicker" style = "display:none;">

$('#popupDatepicker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  gotoCurrent: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  showOn: "both",
  yearRange: "1900:2050",
  autoclose: true,
  closeText: "Close",
  onChangeMonthYear: function(dateText, inst) {
    var today = new Date();

    var date = dateText + "-" + inst + "-" + today.getDate();
  }
});
```

This is HTML and JavaScript code to show datepicker but this code gives error in some devices like safari 10 , chrome 85 (some users). It gives the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$('#popupDatepicker').datepicker...')

I am using jquery-ui 1.12.1 version for datepicker.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping as i mentioned I am using jquery-ui 1.12.1 version for datepicker.

Comment: Sorry my bad missed that one

Comment: you need to include the datepicker library or make sure you are not loading a second jQuery instance

Comment: Also what this means? "chrome 85 (some users)." ? Also, it might be loading scope issue, is datepicker function wrapped in document ready just in case?

Comment: Just to suscribe @PatrickEvans comment; import jquery and datepicker but ensure that it's done exactly in that order.

Comment: @PatrickEvans 
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "{{ asset('js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src = "{{ asset('js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js') }}"></script>

    
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "{{ asset('js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>

These are javascript files which i am including.

Comment: @ikiK Only some users got this error which has google chrome 85 version.

Comment: *some users* - sounds like they might have a cached version of the page?  Just something to rule out